# Show that every symmetric matrix whose entries are calculated as 1/(n−1) has an eigenvalue of 1

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial

I want to prove the following: Every symmetric matrix whose entries are calculated as $ 1/(n -1) $ with $n$ as the size of the matrix, except for the diagonal which is 0, has a characteristic polynomial with a root at $x=1$. In other words, every such matrix has an eigenvalue of 1.

For example Matrix 1:

\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
\end{array}

has a characteristic polynomial:
$f(x)=-x^3+\frac{3 x}{4}+\frac{1}{4} $
,which has a root at $x=1$

Matrix 2:

\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
 \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
 \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\
 \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
\end{array}

has a characteristic polynomial:
$f(x)=-(1/27) - (8 x)/27 - (2 x^2)/3 + x^4 $
,which also has a root at $x=1$

Matrix 3:

\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \\
 \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \\
 \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \\
 \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} \\
 \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
\end{array}

has a characteristic polynomial:
$ f(x)=(4 + 60 x + 320 x^2 + 640 x^3 - 1024 x^5)/1024 $
,which also has a root at $x=1$

I want to show that this is true for any such n by n matrix, i.e. for all n.

Looking for some tips and tricks on how to approach this.

Comment: For example, the matrix with halves is actually $1/2 J - 1/2 I$, where $J$ is the matrix with all entries $1$,and $I$ is the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix. Once you realize what the eigenvalues of $J$ are (it's obvious because it's a rank one matrix) then you can use that post to get your conclusion, which is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A_n$ be the $n\times n$ matrix such as the off-diagonal entries are $1/(n-1)$ and 0 on the diagonal. Then $A_n$ can be written as

$$A_n=\dfrac{1}{n-1}(\mathbf{1}_n\mathbf{1}_n^T-I_{n})$$

where $\mathbf{1}_n$ is the vector of ones of dimension $n$. This matrix is the perturbation of a full-rank matrix $I_n$ by a rank-one matrix $\mathbf{1}_n\mathbf{1}_n^T$. Let $S\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times(n-1)},\tilde S\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ be such that $\mathbf{1}^TS=0$, $S^TS=I$, $\tilde{S}^T\tilde{S}=1$, and $S^T\tilde{S}$.

We can see that the matrix $P=\begin{bmatrix}
S & \tilde S
\end{bmatrix}$ is invertible and orthogonal; i.e. $P^{-1}=P^T$.

Therefore, we can perform a basis change on $A_n$. This shows that the matrix $A_n$ is similar to
$$P^TA_nP=\dfrac{1}{n-1}\begin{bmatrix}
-I_{n-1} & 0\\0 & \tilde S^T(\mathbf{1}_n\mathbf{1}_n^T)\tilde S-1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Noting that $\tilde{S}=\mathbf{1}_n/\sqrt{n}$ is a valid $\tilde S$, then we get that $\tilde S^T(\mathbf{1}_n\mathbf{1}_n^T)\tilde S-1=n-1.$

This yields that that $A_n$ is similar to
$$\dfrac{1}{n-1}\begin{bmatrix}
-I_{n-1} & 0\\0 & n-1
\end{bmatrix},$$

or, equivalently, to
$$\begin{bmatrix}
-\dfrac{1}{n-1}I_{n-1} & 0\\0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

This means that the matrix $A_n$ has one eigenvalue at 1 with multiplicity 1 and one eigenvalue at $-1/(n-1)$ with multiplicity $n-1$.

---

Edit. Example in the case $n=3$. Then, we have that

$$A_3=\dfrac{1}{2}(\mathbf{1}_3\mathbf{1}_3^T-I_{3}).$$

In this case we can compute $S$ and $\tilde S$ as

$$S=\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{-\sqrt{3}}{3} & \dfrac{-\sqrt{3}}{3} \\
\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{6}+\dfrac{1}{2} & \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{6}-\dfrac{1}{2} \\
\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{6}-\dfrac{1}{2} & \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{6}+\dfrac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix},\ \tilde S=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

It is quite tedious to do by hand, but there numerical methods out there that can do that for you.

We then obtain that

$$P^TA_3P=\begin{bmatrix}
-\dfrac{1}{2}I_{2} & 0\\0 & -1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thanks! That one is a bit more complicated, could you illustrate this with an the example 3 x 3 matrix maybe (not a mathematician, sorry)? Would really be helpful in understanding your proof better.

Comment: @holistic The proof is based on the fact that the eigenvalues are invariant when we change basis. So, the idea is just to find a basis where the matrix is diagonal or triangular.  In such cases, the eigenvalues will be the diagonal entries.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. This makes it more clear now!

Comment: I have a question about the proof: Is it possible to also conclude that 1 is the spectral radius of the matrix?

Comment: @holistic The spectral radius of the matrix is the maximum of the eigenvalues in absolute values. So, yes, 1 is the spectral radius of the matrix $A_n$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Answer (score 5):

The vector with all entries equal to $1$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: Thanks. I can't completely follow your reasoning here. How to show, that this is true for every n by n matrix?

Comment: Because when you multiply your $n \times n$ matrix by the vector with all entries equal to $1$, each component of the resulting vector is $\frac{1}{n-1} + \dots + \frac{1}{n-1}$, which has $n-1$ terms, and hence equals $1$.

Comment: Ah I understand now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Note the following lemma:

If the sum of every row of an $ m$ by $m$ matrix $A$ is $k$, then $k$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

**Proof**: Observe that $A[1]_{m\times 1}=k[1]_{m\times 1}$, where $[1]_{m\times 1}$ represents a matrix of order $m$ by $1$, whose every entry equals $1$. QED.

In your case, $k=1$.

Comment: Thanks! That is interesting. Not sure what the notation A[1] is though, could you elaborate please?

Comment: @holistic: I edited my answer almost at the same instant as your comment. Is that clear now?

Comment: Yes thank you. Notation is clear now.